# Lost my Spanish residence card (TIE) and I need to travel to Germany

Tags: schengen, germany, spain

I am an Indonesian student in Spain. I had a student residence card (TIE). But someone stole my wallet, which had my residence card. I'm supposed to go to Germany and stay for 1 and a half months. I paid for the ticket to Germany with Vueling Airlines. I only have my passport and my 3-month expired visa.

So is it possible for me to travel to Germany? What kind of document can I use to prove my TIE was stolen and I am a legal resident?

Thank you.

Comment: If you have not reported the theft yet, do it. Apply for a new TIE. What did they tell you how long it takes?

Comment: A month for a new TIE,  but i should go to germany tomorrow. @o.m.

Comment: Do you have a copy, right?

Comment: I know this isn't an answer but I'm in the same situation right now. I'm kinda desperate so I just wanted to ask, what did you need to present to get a regreso? And did you go through immigration or not? Would really appreciate the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to go to Germany without a problem. I had to apply for an *Autorización de Regreso*. It's a document that proves you have a TIE, but you lost it, or it is expired, and that you are renewing it. If Immigration asks you about your TIE, you can show them your *Autorización de Regreso*.

Comment: Are you sure about that name? *Regreso* with one s is Spanish, but *Ignacio* is a personal name, and apart from a couple of plants named after San Ignacio that's all it is. I can't figure out what it might be a typo for.

Comment: Do you mean "Autorización de Regreso"?

Comment: Ah yes typo. I mean autorizacion de regreso